# Can't import NumPy even though I installed with pip3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, import

Here is what I get when I try to import it

```
>>> import numpy

Python(26024,0x11da32dc0) malloc: can't allocate region
:*** mach_vm_map(size=18446744071675105280, flags: 100) failed (error code=3)
Python(26024,0x11da32dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
init_dgelsd failed init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
```

Here is additional info you might want to know.

1. I installed `numpy`.

   `eric@Erics-MacBook-Pro ~ % pip3 install numpy`

   Requirement already satisfied: `numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.19.2)`
2. I recently erased `oh-my-zsh` but not completely so this always comes when I open terminal.

   `Last login: Tue Oct  6 17:57:22 on ttys002 /Users/eric/.zshrc:source:73: no such file or directory: /Users/eric/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh`

If there is something you need please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the exact same issue while trying to import `pandas` (which requires `numpy`). Basically **Python 3.9** isn't playing nicely with `numpy` on macOS for some very odd reason. Downgraded to **Python 3.8** and everything works perfectly: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-386/.

Comment: Beside I ended up reseting my MacBook(LOL), your answer was the main problem, but there was something more. Matching python version(python2, python3) and numpy version was also important. Because there is preinstalled python2 in MacBook (os is 10.15.7), you have to install python3 first and install bumpy accordingly.

Comment: Fixed it for me!  Downgraded from 3.9 to 3.8 to resolve numpy compatibility problem on MacOS.

Comment: i'm using mac OS big sur and I have python 3.8.2, and yet I still have the problem.

Comment: @xdavidliu I'm also running macOS Big Sur, but I have Python 3.8.6 and don't experience any issues at all. Try to upgrade your Python to the version I mentioned. Good luck!

Comment: @ConstantinMateescu are you using Brew? I'm not. I'm only using the python3 that comes default from Apple.

Comment: @xdavidliu I didn’t install Python 3 via brew nor am I using Apple’s default Python 3. I grabbed Python 3.8.6 from the official website (see the link in the accepted answer above).